# DrawerLayout Does not close after rotate the screen

Tags: android, drawerlayout

so what i am trying is if the DrawerLayout is open and than i rotated the screen the DrawerLayout should close , but it does not

here is the code

```
package com.moammedx.learingmaterial;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NavigationDrwaerFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "testpref";
    public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "user_learnd_drawer";

    private View contenerView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerTolggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;

    public NavigationDrwaerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drwaer, container, false);
    }


    public void SetUp(int fragmenID, DrawerLayout drawerlayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        contenerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmenID);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerlayout;
        mDrawerTolggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerlayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    saveToPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, mUserLearnedDrawer + "");
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onDrawerClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(contenerView);
        }
        if (mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "close now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(contenerView);
        }
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerTolggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerTolggle.syncState();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void saveToPreferences(Context context, String preferencesName, String preferencesValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(preferencesName, preferencesValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferencesName, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(preferencesName, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

the SetUp method is called from the main activity

In the onCreat i checked of savedInstanceState is exist
and later inside the SetUp i used .colseDrawer to close the DrawerLayout , but it does not close , and i added for toast just for test and it show up when i rotate the screen

Comment: Off-topic: As a hypothetical user of your app I'd like the UI same as before screen rotation, if I rotated the phone while having open drawer, I'd like it to remain opened so I can continue where I left off.

Comment: I understand , I'm just asking for my knowledge , and could not find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will i solve it by adding .closeDrawer in onResume

```
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(contenerView);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because the inner workings of the DrawerLayout close command is not wrapped in a post runnable. Meaning, your close command will fire, but before it's state saving kicks in and returns it to it's previous state (in this case open). To fix from your code, simply wrap the contents of your close command in a post runnable. It'll execute after the onCreate() and onRestoreState() are called, closing your drawer on rotation.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to close it on `onRestoreInstanceState`

```
override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START, false)
}
```